# Exclusive Union Manipulation in Set Theory

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I was proving some probability results for the Exclusive Union, and ran into a surprising step in the proof:

**Exclusive Union:** $A \lor B = (A \cup B) \cap (A \cap B)^c$

I then used De Morgan's Law to get:

$A \lor B = (A \cup B) \cap (A^c \cup B^c)$

But the book jumps strait from the initial definition to:

$A \lor B = (A \cap B^c) \cup (B \cap A^c)$

1. How did they arrive at this? Have they rearranged from the De Morgan's Law step as i have, or have they taken a different approach?
2. Is it generally true that: $(A \cup B) \cap (C \cup D) =  (A \cap D) \cup (B \cap C)$ or only in this specific case where $C = A^c$ and $D = B^c$
3. If it is generally true what laws is it using?

I have tried expanding out $(A \cup B) \cap (C \cup D)$ but I get 4 terms, so I don't think im doing it correctly. So I appreciate the help.

Thanks!

Comment: Similar to [a recent comment of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4621082/what-law-of-logic-explains-why-this-is-convertable#comment9744798_4621082), applying distributivity on $A \lor B = (A \cup B) \cap (A^c \cup B^c)$ gives $(A\cap A^c)\cup (A\cap B^c) \cup (B\cap A^c)\cup (B\cap B^c)$, then $(A\cap A^c) = (B\cap B^c)$ are both empty.

Comment: This is super cool. So full disclosure, I realised I had actually expanded out the case of $(A \cap B) \cup (C \cap D)$ and you do get four terms, but obviously this is not the same version I quote in the question. So I assume the way to expand this out is just the logical...$(A \cup C) \cap (A \cup D) \cap (B \cup C) \cap (B \cup D)$.

Comment: Also @peterwhy if you want to copy and paste that as an answer, I'd be more than happy to tick and vote. Honestly it's super helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By applying distributivity on $A \lor B = (A \cup B) \cap (A^c \cup B^c)$ gives $(A\cap A^c)\cup (A\cap B^c) \cup (B\cap A^c)\cup (B\cap B^c)$, then $(A\cap A^c) = (B\cap B^c)$ are both empty.

Alternatively, when starting from $A \lor B = (A \cap B^c) \cup (B \cap A^c)$, expanding it gives $(A\cup B)\cap (A\cup A^c) \cap (B^c\cup B) \cap (B^c\cup A^c)$, then $(A\cup A^c) = (B^c\cup B)$ are both the universal set.

Comment: Great so, implicit in this that my initial step with De Morgan's Law was correct! Thanks!